# Rails Assets intermittent Timeout https://rails-assets.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-assets

Intermittently getting error when doing bundle install for this and also on Continuous Integration server.

```
Retrying dependency api due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Network error while fetching https://rails-assets.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails-assets-angular%2Crails-assets-bootstrap-2.3.2%2Crails-assets-bootstrap-3%2Crails-assets-jasmine%2Crails-assets-jqueryjs%2Crails-assets-rainbow%2Crails-assets-typeahead.js (too many connection resets (due to Net::ReadTimeout - Net::ReadTimeout) after 0 requests on 70190348894440, last used 22.186127 seconds ago)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely maintenance happens every once and awhile (especially this late) although they have definitely had downtime before (see https://github.com/tenex/rails-assets/issues/329).

Doing a simple curl you can see they simply aren't responding to any requests:

```
$ curl 'https://rails-assets.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=rails-assets-angular%2Crails-assets-bootstrap-2.3.2%2Crails-assets-bootstrap-3%2Crails-assets-jasmine%2Crails-assets-jqueryjs%2Crails-assets-rainbow%2Crails-assets-typeahead.js' -D - --max-time 10
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 10004 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```